# How do you do "Filter-style search" mentioned in Busy Coder's Guide at page 2521?

Tags: android

In the program below you can search for data and the data is displayed automatically without pressing an additional return (like AutoCompleteTextView):

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/SearchView

In the program below you have to press return to get the result, thus it's not automatically displayed when typing in a search text:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Search/Lorem

Is this possible to get the data here automatically without pressing return with the Search framework from Android?

I also noticed you mention "Filter-style search" (page 2521), but it's not described in the book? Is this the way to go if you want to achieve the result automatically without pressing return or what is "Filter-style search"?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will have much better luck with your questions here if you explain in the question what you are trying, instead citing books that not everyone helping here will have. "it's not described in the book?" -- correct. I have not worked with Android's search hooks in years.

Comment: Since they seem to have pulled any discussion of filtering options in search from the documentation (based on a quick scan), I will pull the reference to filtering options from my chapter in the next book update. Again, I have not worked with Android's search hooks in years.

Comment: OK. I just found something from Android samples SearchableDictionary. Looks like it does what I want. Thanks for a great book.